# Percentage in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to design something like this, what should I do in Flutter?
[image]

I used some packages but my problem was not solved

Comment: You have to check how animations work in Flutter.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.